# Семь раз закрой, а не сработает, или поставь плюсик комментарию?

Tags: обсуждение

[Как несовершеннолетним подросткам зарабатывать в Google Play?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496279/178988)

Тематичность подобных вопросов обсуждалась на мете. Но мне интересно другое. Вопрос задан вчера, т. е. голоса за закрытие на нём сгореть не могли.

Активных голосов за закрытие сейчас 2, оба с причиной

> Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

причина кастомная, поэтому есть комментарий с тем же текстом. На этом комментарии 7 плюсов. Получается, скорее всего, эту причину закрытия выбирало 8 человек.

Как получилось, что в истории вопроса нет закрытия?

Конечно, голоса могли добавляться и отзываться, но при минимум 8 голосах не набрать ни в какой момент 5, кажется весьма нереалистичным...

Или кто-то просто плюсует комментарий о закрытии, но реально не голосует?

Comment: вроде есть голоса за отмену закрытия (или что происходит когда в очереди жмешь "оставить открытым")

Comment: @Abyx, ничего не происходит. Просто после нескольких таких вопрос из очереди выкинется. На число голосов это никак не влияет. Есть только отмена самим голосующим, но 8 - это слишком много, и, получается, люди должны были голосовать за закрытие уже после обсуждения на мете, а в таком случае ещё два отзыва голосов - это странно. Да и вообще, нереалистичная картина получается. А у Юрия хорошая версия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Голосовавших за закрытие было меньше, чем плюсов на комменте. А плюсы ставили люди, хотевшие закрыть, но не имевшие достаточных привелегий.

Comment: Хорошая версия :) Я что-то даже не подумал, что те, кто проголосовать не может, могут таким образом высказывать своё мнение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я сам так пару раз делал. Вроде и надо закрыть, но рука не поднимается. Так что просто голосовал за коммент)

Comment: Проверил в истории тревог на вопросе. Именно так и происходило.